# Grunt installation in windows

Tags: windows, gruntjs, installation

I am trying to install grunt in my system windows 7. I have downloaded grunt from github. When running grunt command its giving `unrecognised command`. Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: What command exactly are you running, and what's the exact error?

Comment: i am running grunt --help just to check the installation of grunt.

Comment: you know how to install grunt,like how to configure the environment variable for grunt etc,i dont have any idea,i have simply downloaded grunt folder from github,

Answer (score 0):

You can install grunt globally via npm (downloading it from here https://nodejs.org/download/). Probably you will need to update your environmental variables (by adding '%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm' to $PATH) or simply restart your PC.

Then you should be able to run `npm install -g grunt-cli` from your PowerShell or Command Line. When the npm installation is ready you should have access to grunt command.